# app:config:import does not update web/secure/base_url

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, core-config-data

We have defined the default `web/secure/base_url` like this in our `app/etc/env.php` of our Magento **2.4.2-p1** CE for example:

```php
return [
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'web' => [
                'unsecure' => [
                    'base_url' => 'http://example.com/',
                ],
                'secure' => [
                    'base_url' => 'https://example.com/',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

However, if we change these values in the `env.php` and then execute

```bash
$ bin/magento app:config:import
Processing configurations data from configuration file...
System config was processed
```

the actual database values in `core_config_data` do not change for the `default` scope of the `web/secure/base_url` path - even though the command confirmed *"System config was processed"* instead of *"Nothing to import."*. Curiously these values cannot be edited in the back end, as they are otherwise identified to be persisted via the config files.

We would like to persist the default base URLs for the respective environment via the `env.php` this way - however for some reason Magento is not actually updating the value in the database when executing `setup:upgrade` or `app:config:import`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual values of **unsecure** and **secure** url path in the database `core_config_data` are not getting changed because

Magento directly uses values in the system array in the config.php or env.php files instead of importing them into the database because they require some pre- and post-processing actions.

See official [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html#system-configuration) for more details.

If you want to write this values to env.php and also get it updated in the database, then try to set this configuration value using command line

`bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/unsecure/base_url http://example.com/`

Where `--lock-env` parameter either locks the value so it cannot be edited in the Magento Admin or changes a setting that is already locked in the Magento Admin. The command writes the value to the `<Magento base dir>/app/etc/env.php` file.

Check [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html) for more details. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I saw in the documentation afterwards, that these values are pulled directly from the config, instead of the database. However, in our case that did not work for some reason. Magento still used the `base_url` of the database for the back end and tried to redirect to that `base_url` instead of using the new base url from the `env.php`.

Comment: In that case try to set configuration value using command line.